# Using RegEx in Python to extract contents

Tags: python, regex

Good evening,

I am very new to Python and RegEx. I have the following sentence:

```
-75.76 Card INSURANCEGrabPay ASIA DIRECT to Paid AM 1:16 +100.00 3257 UpAmex Top PM 9:55 +300.00 3257 UpAmex Top PM 9:55 -400.00 Card LTDGrabPay PTE AXS to Paid PM 9:57 (SGD) Amount Details Time here. appear will transactions cashless your All 2022 Feb 15 on made transactions GrabPay points 52 earned points Rewards 475.76 SGD spent Amount 0.24 SGD balance Wallet 2022 Feb 15 Summary statement daily your here
```

I would like to search for just '-' and the amount after that.

After that, I would like to skip 2 words and extract ALL words if need be in a single group (I will read more about groups but for now i would need in a single group, which i can later use to split and get the words from that string) just before 'Paid'

For instance, I would get

```
-75.76 ASIA Direct to
-400 PTE AXS to
```

What would be the regex command? Also, is there a good regex tutorial where I can read up on?

Comment: `"...and the amount after that."` is vague. Be precise! That's what coding is all about. What if the string (not "sentence") were, "-400.00 Card -  XYZ - 2", what Python object should be returned? Sorry, but SO is not the place to solicit suggestions about books, articles, tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have created one match having 2 groups ie, group1 for the amount and group2 for all the words (that include "to " string also).

Regex:

```
(-\d+\.?\d+) \w+ \w+ ([\w ]+)?Paid
```

You can check the details here: https://regex101.com/r/eUMgdW/1

Python code:

```
import re
output = re.findall("""(-\d+\.?\d+) \w+ \w+ ([\w ]+)?Paid""", your_input_string)

for found in output:
    print(found)

#('-75.76', 'ASIA DIRECT to ')
#('-400.00', 'PTE AXS to ')
```

Comment: one more note: you have tons and tons of material on youtube which you can go through, you won't be needing any paid course for that. Regex101 is a great one where you can experiment as you progress.
And, be cautious while applying concepts between languages because regex rules are different from one language to the other due to many edge cases and different engines they use.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than give you the actual regex, I'll gently nudge you in the right direction. It's more satisfying that way.

"Words" here are seperated by spaces. So what you're searching for is a group of characters (captured), a space, characters again, space, characters, space, then capture everything and end with "PAID". Try to create a regex to do that.

If you'd like to brush up on regex, check out [Regex101](https://regex101.com). It's a web tool to test out regex, along with a debugger and a cheat sheet.